# How do I open the path of an item in a combobox while also only displaying the file name?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, winforms

I am searching for exe files in a folder and displaying the file names in a combobox to be selected by the user. When the user presses a button the file selected should be opened. This works if I display the file path rather than the file name in the combobox.

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\myFolder\", "*.exe");
    foreach (string file in filePaths)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object b = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    string be = Convert.ToString(b);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(be);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the program to be executed you need the entire path. For the display it should suffice to give the user a name for orientation. Now the only thing left is to map one to the other. For this you could use a simple dictionary. Collect all names as keys and the corresponding paths as values. Display only the names.

```
private Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\myFolder\", "*.exe");
    foreach (string fullPath in filePaths)
    {
        string displayName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
        map.Add(displayName, fullPath);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(displayName);
    }
}
```

Then retrieve the path from the dictionary using the name as the key

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string nameKey = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string executablePath = map[nameKey];
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(executablePath);
}
```

Edit:

As suggested by Panagiotis Binding example:

To use binding you would need to specify what is displayed and what is treated as value in the combobox. You do that by telling the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` which property of the dictionary it should use. Furthermore the dictionary has to be encompassed by a `BindingSource`.

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\myFolder\", "*.exe");
    foreach (string fullPath in filePaths)
    {
        string displayName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
        map.Add(displayName, fullPath);
    }

    comboBox1.DisplayMember="Key";
    comboBox1.ValueMember="Value";
    comboBox1.DataSource= new BindingSource(map, null);
}
```

In this example you would need to use the `SelectedValue` property to retrieve the value of the dictionary item, namely the full path. You can use it directly

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the dictionary lookup. Data binding already handles this scenario. In fact, it may be possible to bind to the directory and use `Key` as `DisplayMember` and `Value` as the `ValueMember` removing the need for casts, `ToString()` and lookups

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ah now I understood you. Thank you for your comment. I made an edit and incorporated your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use data binding instead of adding items one by one, and specify which property you want to display using the `DisplayMember` property. [How to: Bind a Windows Forms ComboBox or ListBox Control to Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-a-windows-forms-combobox-or-listbox-control-to-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) shows how data binding works.

One option is to load the list of all files as FileInfo objects and set them to the combo's `DataSource` property, and use `Name` as the DisplayMember:

```
FileInfo[] _files=Array.Empty<FileInfo>();

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DisplayMember="Name";
    var folder=new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\myFolder\");
    _files=folder.GetFiles("*.exe");
   comboBox1.DataSource=_files;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = (FileInfo)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file.FullName);
}
```

You can set the `DisplayMember` in the combo's properties too.

`FileInfo` doesn't have a property to return the name without an extension and `DisplayMember` doesn't accept expressions. If you need to display the name, you can create your own class to hold the file and name:

```
class MyFile
{
    public FileInfo File {get;set;}
    public string Name=>Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File.FullName);
}


    MyFile[] _files=Array.Empty<MyFile>();

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DisplayMember="Name";
        var folder=new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\myFolder\");
        _files=folder.EnumerateFiles("*.exe")
                     .Select(f=> new MyFile{File=file})
                     .ToArray();
       comboBox1.DataSource=_files;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var file = (MyFile)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file.File.FullName);
    }
```

Comment: ah yes, a databding example. I would accept this as answer, as it is the more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put strings into the `ComboBox` - you can put other objects in, and the `ComboBox` will use `.ToString()` to get the string to display.

That means you can write a wrapper class like so to include the information you need:

```
public sealed class FileInformation
{
    public FileInformation(string fullFilename)
    {
        FullFilename = fullFilename;
        Filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullFilename);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Filename;
    }

    public string FullFilename { get; }
    public string Filename { get; }
}
```

Then your code to populate the `ComboBox` would look something like this:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\bin\", "*.exe");
foreach (string file in filePaths)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new FileInformation(file));
}
```

And the button handler could look like this:

```
var info = (FileInformation) comboBox1.SelectedItem;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info.FullFilename);
```